# Shell script to count the the number of files modified in svn repo

Tags: shell, svn, unix, scripting

I have a svn repository. I want to know the number of files added, deleted, modified between 2 dates. I can use svn log.
svn log -v -r {2013-12-01}:{2013-12-31} url 
to get changed paths which will show added, deleted,modified file paths altogther. But I want only count seperately like

No of files added : 55
No of files deleted :2
No of files modified :22
as output.

Also I want to get the date from user from the terminal. 
How to write shell script for this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the counts use the [status code](http://gotofritz.net/blog/howto/svn-status-codes/) which is the letter on the fourth (4th) position of the svn log output, e.g. M means modified, A added, D deleted

number of modified paths:

```
svn log -v -r {2013-12-01}:{2013-12-31} | grep "^...M" | uniq | wc -l
```

EDIT:
sorry for wrong URL, those are svn status codes, not svn log codes. Looks like svn log can give you A (added), M (modified), D (deleted) or R (replaced)